# Crop an image by drawing with finger touches in android

Tags: android, android-intent

I am working on an application wherein the user draws some closed area on an image. I want to crop any closed area drawn on that image. In a way I would like to achieve this functionality in this app
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/cut-me-in-easy-to-use-photo/id556546026?mt=8.

I have done the drawing part using touches method and i could not cut the exact image can please suggest how can it possible.

Comment: Have you find your questions ans or not